# Creating custom shapes

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity, there are some pre-made meshes like Cubes, Spheres, etc.

But what if I want to, for example, make a Ring shape? What are the steps I should follow to make or import such a shape into my Unity project?

Comment: use e.g. [Blender](https://www.blender.org) it is OpenSource -> free. Export models to `FBX` and drag them into the Asset folder. Or for the fun of it: calculate and [create your mesh](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/projects/procedural-cave-generation-tutorial/creating-meshes) completely by c# script setting vertices, triangle faces uvs etc by yourself :P

Answer (score 1):

You would make such a shape as a mesh in your modelling software of choice, then export it to Unity, generally FBX suffices.

Unity's stock shapes are there to allow you to prototype levels and game mechanics, they aren't intended to be comprehensive, either for basic game creation or for level design.

In particular, building things in Unity out of the basic meshes, such as levels and characters, is much less efficient than modelling those objects in their entirety in modelling software and exporting that.